# Restricting a user to enter more than 7 digits before decimel and 3 after decimel

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a user input from user in a textbox, but i need to validate it

1.It should not take more than 7 digits before decimel

2.it should not take more than 3 digits after decimel

I actually figured out the 2nd part,,but first part is still a problem
my regular expression is:

```
/^([0-9]{0,7})+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/
```

Tell me where i m going wrong

Suggest a valid regularexpression

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the plus, and I would use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` but I don't know that it is any faster:

```
/^\d{0,7}(\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

The reason your regex failed is that you had the `+` sign after your first test which means "one or more matches". So it was looking for on or more sets of `[0-9]{0,7}` which would match any number of characters before the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

`/^\d{1,7}\.\d{1,3}$/`

This will match 1-7 digits dot 1-3 digits.  Are either the integer or decimal required? Is .333 or 333 valid?