# How to restrict user to enter 6 digits after decimal using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a numeric type input box. What i need is to restrict user to enter not more than 6 digits after decimal. I searched some but all i got is the `max` and `step` property. Is it possible using any html attribute? Will be ok with a javascript solution as well but **html solution will be preferable.**

Comment: you will have to use Javascript ... pure html solution is to provide two input boxes with a dot in between and limiting the second box to 6 characters

Comment: Try to handle input box key press event by javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830626/restricting-a-user-to-enter-more-than-7-digits-before-decimel-and-3-after-decime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With today's HTML support, before we have [the pattern attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute), you can't do it without JavaScript.

Here's a JavaScript based solution preventing any bad input :

```
var lastValue='';
yourinput.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (!/^\d*\.?\d{0,6}$/.test(this.value)){
    this.value = lastValue;
  }
  lastValue = this.value;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uxezun/1/edit)

Instead of preventing the input, you could also simply display a message :

```
<input id=yourinput pattern="\d+">
<span id=bad style="display:none;color:red">BAD</span>


document.getElementById('yourinput').onkeyup = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('bad').style.display = 
    /^\d*\.?\d{0,6}$/.test(this.value) ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uxezun/2/edit)

Comment: +1 for showing an error message on exceeding limit, however i am ok with preventing the user from entering more than 6 digits after decimal.